# Trying to add a link within a gridview

Tags: gridview, hyperlink

I have create a sql database and one of the columns called "Link" has the website url for sites within my website as well as outside my website.  Example I have a link to Geico insurance.  The problem is when I add this column to my gridview it just shows the url for the website.  I need it to be a link to the website that I can click on and display in a new page and I just want the word "website" as the link.

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="apps2" GridLines="Vertical" AllowSorting="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Link" Text="Website" DataNavigateUrlFields="Link" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}" target=_blank/>
        </asp:HyperLinkField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Source" HeaderText="Source" SortExpression="Source">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Primary_Number" HeaderText="Phone Number" SortExpression="Primary_Number">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Backup_Number" HeaderText="Backup Number" SortExpression="Backup_Number">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fax_Number" HeaderText="Fax Number" SortExpression="Fax_Number">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Alarm_Reset_Code" HeaderText="Alarm Reset Code" SortExpression="Alarm_Reset_Code">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Contact_Name" HeaderText="1st Contact Name" SortExpression="First_Contact_Name">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Contact_Number" HeaderText="1st Contact #" SortExpression="First_Contact_Number">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Second_Contact_Name" HeaderText="2nd Contact Name" SortExpression="Second_Contact_Name">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Second_Contact_Number" HeaderText="2nd Contact #" SortExpression="Second_Contact_Number">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Third_Contact_Name" HeaderText="3rd Contact Name" SortExpression="Third_Contact_Name">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Third_Contact_Number" HeaderText="3rd Contact #" SortExpression="Third_Contact_Number">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Modified" HeaderText="Date Modified" SortExpression="Modified">
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
```

When I use this script The gridview does not launch on my website.  I get a server error and hilighted in the error is the line for the hyperlinkfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off using **[`<ItemTemplate>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)** for Gridview for displaying links to website. That way you can fully customize the UI/Design of HyperLink Columns.

Example:

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <a href="<%# Bind("Link") %>" target="_blank">Website</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
```